# Adding Duplicate Image Greatly Lowers Framerate

Tags: processing

I'm having a very strange issue with a project I'm working on. When I try to display a duplicate of an already working image, the framerate drops horribly. I've tried making a second contructor for the alternate image, duplicating the image and displaying the duplicate, etc.. No matter what i do, the issue still persists. [Here's the project.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aOGZ3nPzypv0jS2Eau4QUHeZ4p6refJ9/view?usp=sharing) The line of code that keeps breaking the framerate is inside of "Game", and is the following:

```
a2.display();
```

If you remove that line, the framerate goes back to normal.

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `loadImage()` should be called inside the class constructor or the setup function.  The function is slow and only needs to be called once at the beginning of the game, to load an image from disk.  In fact, this is the reason why games have load screens when starting up a level, because they are loading all images and assets from disk, and that takes time.

Specifically: move `img = loadImage("PurpleSpaceship.png");` out of the `display()` function and into the `Ship(int x, int y, int w, int h)` function instead.

On the topic of optimization, you could have a single variable which holds the image, outside of the class, that is loaded only once even with many ships.  But then, instances of you class would be sharing that data.  Sharing can lead to bugs and confusion, as your program gets bigger and more complex.  Or generally speaking, optimizing code tends to reduce its stability and create problems, so, it's good to seek compromise and to find "just enough" optimization.